# Reversed order when mapping array to struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, mapping

In my header file I defined...

```
struct MD5_packet   {

union{
    unsigned long int longInt;
    struct {
        unsigned char           byte0;
        unsigned char           byte1;
        unsigned char           byte2;
        unsigned char           byte3;  
        }bytesA;    
    }unionA;

  ...   % 4 similar unions are also defined here with just the names differing

  }
```

Then in main I've declared...

```
struct MD5_packet *MD5_data;
unsigned char __attribute__ ((aligned (64))) state[88];
```

After a certain process, I am interested in mapping the first 16 bytes of `state` into either a few `unsigned long int` or `unsigned int` unions which are part of the `MD5_data` struct. The above code shows the struct definition for `MD5_packet` with member `longInt` where my hope is to simply map the first 4 bytes of `state` to the `longInt` union. This way I can then use `MD5_data->unionA.longInt` to access the variable and assign it where needed.  I am trying to avoid having to use a struct with 16 chars and a ton of bit operations to assign to variables I'll use later on.

So in implementation...

```
MD5_data = (unsigned long int) &state[0];
unsigned long int anotherLongInt;
anotherLongInt = MD5_data->unionA.longInt;
```

The result is below. As you can see the individual bytes are mapped correctly but then their order is the reverse of what I would expect when represented by `longInt`. The value of `anotherLongInt` is written to but also in reverse order.

[image: Watch window results]

Side note:
I get a compiler warning for the `&state[0]` assignment even though I've cast it. Apparently this is not the best way so any guidance for this would help.

```
Assignment makes pointer form integer without a cast
```

Answer (score 0):

Byte order in `int` or `long` depends on the platform (search for "little endian" or "big endian" in the internet).

EDIT:

for common little/big endian platforms you can declare your `structA` as

```
 #include <endian.h>
 ...

 struct {
 #if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
     unsigned char byte3;
     unsigned char byte2;
     ...
 #else
     unsigned char byte0;
     unsigned char byte1;
     ...
 #endif
 } bytesA;
```

Comment: Is there any way to enforce a certain endianness for just this mapping so the order is correct?

Comment: So this #ifdef block would go inside the struct > union > struct definition? I don't understand why reversing the order of names byte3...byte2...byte1... or byte0...byte1...byte2... makes any different since they are just variable names. The name won't define the order.

Comment: I'm using C30 compiler and cannot find endian.h in the MPLABC30 include files. Is there another way to declare the order?

Comment: endianess (and the byteorder) is not defined by C but platform dependent (<endian.h> is coming from BSD).  You will have to read documentation of your compiler whether there is something similar. Perhaps, search for 'endian' in the system headers will reveal these information.

Comment: Any suggestions on addressing the warning I received from the assignment?